# PySpark: creating new RDD from existing LabeledPointsRDD but modifying the label

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Is there a quick way to create a new RDD from an existing RDD that contains LabeledPoints, but only modify the labels for each row?

As an example, assume I have RDD called myRDD, and that myRDD has LabeledPoints as follow:

```
RDD = sc.parallelize([
    LabeledPoint(1, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]),
    LabeledPoint(2, [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),
    LabeledPoint(4, [6.0, 7.0, 8.0])])
```

This represents a take(5) of the RDD.

I want to simply create a new RDD from this one but I want to subtract 10 from each label.

When I try this, it fails miserably:

```
myRDD = RDD.map(lambda x: x[0].label - 10, x[1].features)
```

Please help me by also pointing out what is wrong with my reasoning in above attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is wrong with your reasoning in above attempt?

First lets take a look at a whole map:

```
 map(lambda x: x[0].label - 10, x[1].features)
```

Right now it interpreted as `map` with function `lambda x: x[0].label - 10` and some additional argument `x[1].features`. Let's start with returning a tuple:

```
map(lambda x: (x[0].label - 10, x[1].features)))
```

Function passed to map receives a single point at the time so indexing doesn't make sense, you should simply acceess `label` and `features`:

```
 map(lambda x: (x.label - 10, x.features))
```

Finally you have to create a new point:

```
map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x.label - 10, x.features))
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! For my sanity - why do I have to re-create as LabeledPoint - the RDD was already created with each row being a LabeledPoint, hence my thinking that I could just change the label values and maintain the "labeledpointedness" of the RDD? Is it the mere fact that I apply some form of manipulation via map that necesitates this explicit re-Labelpointing?

Comment: Almost every data structure you normally use in Spark is immutable. Even if it wasn't anonymous functions are not a right place to mutate state, especially if you have to use statements.